# undefined symbol: kms_element_get_type

Tags: gstreamer, kurento

I'm  creating custom Kurento modules with GStreamer plugins, I have created a new module named "RtmpEndpoint" which extends Endpoint.
I was able to build and install the module and generate client js API to use.
However the module could not be loaded, the error log shows:

> (gst-plugin-scanner:3379): GStreamer-WARNING *: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/librtmpendpoint.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/librtmpendpoint.so: **undefined symbol: kms_element_get_type**

I did defined the kms_rtmp_endpoint_get_type() function in the source and header file, I'm confused why this error is happening, please help , thanks.

the header file:

```
typedef struct _KmsRtmpEndpoint KmsRtmpEndpoint;
typedef struct _KmsRtmpEndpointClass KmsRtmpEndpointClass;

struct _KmsRtmpEndpoint
{
  KmsElement element;

  GstElement *h264depay;
  GstElement *pcmudepay;
  GstElement *flvmuxer;
  GstElement *rtmpsink;

  GstPad *videoPad, *audioPad;

  gboolean silent;
};

struct _KmsRtmpEndpointClass 
{
  KmsElementClass parent_class;
};

GType kms_rtmp_endpoint_get_type (void);
```

and part of the source file:

```
static GstStaticPadTemplate video_sink = GST_STATIC_PAD_TEMPLATE ("video",
GST_PAD_SINK,
GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
GST_STATIC_CAPS ("application/x-rtp, "
    "media = (string) \"video\", "
    "clock-rate = (int) 90000, " "encoding-name = (string) \"H264\"")
);

static GstStaticPadTemplate audio_sink = GST_STATIC_PAD_TEMPLATE ("audio",
GST_PAD_SINK,
GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
GST_STATIC_CAPS ("application/x-rtp, "
    "media = (string) \"audio\", "
    "payload = (int) " GST_RTP_PAYLOAD_PCMU_STRING ", "
    "clock-rate = (int) 8000; "
    "application/x-rtp, "
    "media = (string) \"audio\", "
    "encoding-name = (string) \"PCMU\", clock-rate = (int) [1, MAX ]")
);

#define kms_rtmp_endpoint_parent_class parent_class
G_DEFINE_TYPE (KmsRtmpEndpoint, kms_rtmp_endpoint, KMS_TYPE_ELEMENT);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you shouldn't define `kms_rtmp_endpoint_get_type()` in the source file, `G_DEFINE_TYPE` will auto generate it.